# React toggle button based on API return

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on a React application.

As you can see in the following code, there are two buttons. I would like to show the grey button if the user hasn't created a Request (default). If the user has created a Request the button should be green.

**Problem:** 
The main issue is, that the map function (API) no returning any value for "no Requests" so I am not able to identify "no Requests". That means that .isEmpty,.length, .indexOf,... and also the "if-else" is not working because there is nothing to validate.

```
      const greenButton = (
    <Button color="green" onClick={e => DeleteRequest(e, rest.id)}>Request</Button>
  );

  const greyButton = (
    <Button color="grey" onClick={e => CreateRequest(e, props.reservationID)}>Request</Button>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {greyButton}

      {requests.map((rest, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          {rest.requester === username
            ? <div>{greenButton}{rest.requester} <i
              aria-hidden="true"
              className="delete icon"
              onClick={e => DeleteRequest(e, rest.id)} />
            </div> : <div />}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Result in the UI:

[image]

API: 
[image]

Any Ideas? (If you need more information, I am happy to provide more details)

Comment: Your API should return an empty array [ ] for 'no request', this would make it easier to test in your render function

Comment: Are you trying to display a grey button if no requests, and if there are requests map them to a bunch of green buttons?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes!

Comment: @HermitCrab: I guess this is not an option.

Comment: Can you share what your initial state of `requests` is in your component?

Comment: @DrewReese I added it to the question.

Comment: Sorry. I meant your actual component code. What, if any, is your component's initial state, and the function that updates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Use a ternary on `requests` being a defined/truthy object **and** has a truthy length property. In the true branch map the requests, grey button in false branch. This covers `requests` being either initially (or returned from the API) `undefined` or an empty array `[]`.

```
return (
  <div>
    {requests && requests.length ? requests.map((rest, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        {rest.requester === username
          ? <div>{greenButton}{rest.requester} <i
            aria-hidden="true"
            className="delete icon"
            onClick={e => DeleteRequest(e, rest.id)} />
          </div> : <div />}
      </div>
    )) : (
      {greyButton}
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Wow! I am impressed, it is working. I will add <div></div> around the {greyButton}